# delete data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've following output code
[image]

I want to remove position from array. When I try `delete $products.position;` It is not deleting. But When I try `delete $products[0].position;` It is deleting only from first.

Comment: As you already know `$products` is an array, so iterate and use `delete` operator. You should search "How to iterate an array?"

Comment: luckily this isn't JSON, but a palin ol' javascript Object - doing this with JSON would be painful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through the elements of the array and delete `position` from each.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $products.length; i++) {
   delete $products[i].position;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `map` instead of `forEach`.

```js
const products = [{ foo: 'bar', position: 1 }, { foo: 'baz', position: 2}, { doo: 'daz' }];
console.log(products.map(obj => delete obj.position && obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Although it is probably less readable it makes more sense to me because you want to generate a new array applying a `delete` function to each element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products.forEach(function(item){ 
    delete item.position; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to remove an JSON object from particular position from an array, but I will recommended to use splice method since its comparatively faster then other methods.

```
products.splice(position, 1);
```

The first parameter indicates the position to start from and the second indicates the number of objects you want to splice. Since you only want to remove one object, so it should be written 1(one). Position here starts from 0(zero) so insert the position accordingly.

Comment: A Javascript Error occured Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined http://local:8181/js/actions.js 430 22 ReferenceError: position is not defined.

Comment: var position = 1; // Example to remove object at second position then use the above code. I thing you might not have defined the position variable

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```
for(var i in $products){
    delete $products[i].position;
}
```